# why "google is not defined " when i load google js api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i follow  the [api](http://code.google.com/intl/zh-CN/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_javascript.html) step by step,but can't load successful..

this is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body >
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload=%7B%22modules%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22gdata%22%2C%22version%22%3A%222.x%22%2C%5B%22callback%22%3A%22onLoad%22%2C%22packages%22%3A%5B%22maps%22%5D%5D%7D%5D%7D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var service = new google.gdata.maps.MapsService('docs-example');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the error is :google is not defined

why ??

---

**upedted**

i change my code,and it worked,but it fire the errorHandler and then  alert "error!!!":

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body >
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the latest version of the Google Data JavaScript Client
  google.load('gdata', '2.x', {packages: ['maps']});

  function onGoogleDataLoad() {
    // Put your code here
  }

  // Call function once the client has loaded
  google.setOnLoadCallback(onGoogleDataLoad);

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var service = new google.gdata.maps.MapsService('docs-example');
listMaps()
function listMaps() {
  var list = document.createElement('ul');
  var mapFeedUrl = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/feeds/maps/default/owned';

  service.getMapFeed(mapFeedUrl, function(feedRoot) {
    var feed = feedRoot.feed;
    var entries = feed.getEntries();
    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
      var entry = entries[i];
      var mapTitle = entry.getTitle().getText();
      var listItem = document.createElement('li');
      var listText = document.createTextNode(mapTitle);
      listItem.appendChild(listText);
      list.appendChild(listItem);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(list);
  }, errorHandler)
}
function errorHandler(){
    alert('error!!!')
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

why ?

thanks

Comment: have you tried this http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html

Answer (score 1):

you should put any call to the google stuff inside the `onGoogleDataLoad()` function to make sure it is not launched before the APIs have finished loading.

```
function onGoogleDataLoad() {
  var service = new google.gdata.maps.MapsService('docs-example');
  listMaps()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the JS URL with your browser, you get the following result:

```
var error = new Error("Invalid autoload.");
error.toString = function() { return this.message; }
throw error;
```

Meaning, there's something wrong with your URL.