# Google is not defined using Google Visualization API; possibly jQuery's fault

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

I'm getting the same error as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513495/why-google-is-not-defined-when-i-load-google-js-api) to which there is no answer. To elaborate, I'm trying to load [this demo](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/intensitymap.html) in my code. I've altered it slightly in that I am not including their code in any header tag - this particular code fragment will be loaded in by jQuery. Anyway, so my code looks like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' 
        src='https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAKl2DNx3pM....'>
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', '', 'Country');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Population (mil)', 'a');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Area (km2)', 'b');
    data.addRows(5);
    data.setValue(0, 0, 'CN');
    data.setValue(0, 1, 1324);
    data.setValue(0, 2, 9640821);
    data.setValue(1, 0, 'IN');
    data.setValue(1, 1, 1133);
    /* ... */
    var chart = new google.visualization.IntensityMap(
                  document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['intensitymap']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
});
</script>
```

This section of code lies in a div whose visibility is toggled as needed. The whole lot (the entire page here) is returned as the result of an ajax call.

The theory here being using jQuery's `$(document).ready()` handler means that google should be loaded when the document is ready.

However, I'm getting this:

[image: Google is not defined error message screenshot.]

Regardless of whether that section is inside `ready()` or not. Now here's the real kicker: in the dom explorer, I can find said object:

[image: So google does actually exist. This picture proves it.]

Can anyone please explain to me firstly why this is happening and then what I do to fix it?

Being a naive kind of javascript developer, I tried including the google scripts in my head tags. That then produced something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249030/is-not-defined-error-using-jquery-and-google-code-repository) ($ not defined) except that we're not loading jQuery from google, we're hosting it locally.

We successfully load a number of other jQuery extensions inline this way as well as extra parts of jQuery code, so to my mind this should work. I do not know whether jQuery is getting in the way of Google/vice versa but they shouldn't be.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Removing $(document).ready should fix your problem.  I tried your code and after commenting out $(document).ready, it worked:

```
//$(document).load(function() {
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['intensitymap']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
//});
```

Now as for why this is the case, I do not know... In any case, you shouldn't need to wait for document.ready to call google.load; google.load will ensure that by the time your callback drawChart is called, it will be safe to execute.

Comment: Thanks @Karl, I've tried that too though I'm afraid; some problem, same symptoms. I went down the document ready route on the assumption that I needed to wait for google's stuff to load...

Comment: Aaah I've fixed it - those items needed to be in the `<head>` tags and just as you say, I don't need need `$(document).ready()`. Have a tick.

Comment: As for "Why": Google's script loader uses `document.write` to load scripts dynamically. When it's deferred, either using a load/domready event, or using `setTimeout`, the current document will be overwritten, breaking your code - [Related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9748617/938089?mysterious-object-doesnt-support-this-methoderror-in-ie8-on-google-load).

Answer (score 4):

You can load the the charts after the page has loaded but with a special callback.

google.load("visualization", "1", {"callback" : drawChart});

https://developers.google.com/loader/#Dynamic